# Phonegap card scanning plugin for UWP

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, uwp

I am in dire need of a card scanning plugin for Phonegap if such a thing exists. Alternatively being pointed in the right direction for making my own... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you mean credit card scanning,try [card.io](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Cordova-Plugin).

Comment: That is exactly what I checked out... No UWP support as far as I am aware.